# Load all images from internal application

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flex4, adobe, flash-builder

I am trying to load all the .png files from an internal application folder into a list control and I am stuck on exactly how to do it. I have tried httpservice to get the folder and count how many images there are so I can loop through them but I just cant figure that out.

File structure

```
-src
    -(default package)
        -my application files
    -icons
        -all my .png files
```

httpService i tried:

```
<s:HTTPService id="loadAllImages" destination="/icons" result="gotImages(event)" fault="loadAllImagesFault(event)"/>
```

This always results in directory not found. Am I going about this completely wrong? Anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this. To store an image within an Flash application (SWF or AIR), you **must** embed it either using `@Embed('')` in MXML or by using the [Class] method.

The only way to actually reveal a folder directory of an internal folder in an AIR app is by using File (which is an AIR only class).

```
var file:File = File.applicationDirectory;
file.browseForDirectory('icons'); ; //unsure if that will pull an internal folder or not, but you get the idea
```

If this is an external directory (doesn't sound like it is), I believe you would do it how you show in your question (although I have never needed to use this method, so I don't know if/how it works)

Comment: I am familiar with Embed, but my issue is that I need to embed all the images in the folder and I have no idea how many images there are as they may change. So I was hoping that there was a way to loop through all the images with a counter.

Comment: No, there isn't. The images must be embedded at compile-time, not a run-time. So the only time the images in the folder could *ever* change is when you recompile the app.

Comment: Ok, well, I guess I will have to do what I really didnt want to do... write all my png file names into an xml file and load that to get the length so I can loop through... Oh, and store the files outside of the application. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry the answer was pretty much the exact opposite of what you wanted. It's just how Flash works, unfortunately.